# How do decode base64 file when reading from GridFS via Node?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, base64, gridfs

I'm trying to read a file encoded in base64 from a MongoDB GridFS collection using Node. I have been able to get the file saved from MongoDB to my local machine, but it's in base64 format and I want to save it unencoded.

Ideally I would like to decode the file "on-the-fly" without having to save once, to then read > decode > write it back to the filesystem.

My code currently looks like this...

```
return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    let bucket = new mongodb.GridFSBucket(db, {bucketName: 'Binaries'});
    let objectID = new mongodb.ObjectID(fileID);

    // create the download stream
    bucket.openDownloadStream(objectID)
        .once('error', async (error) => {
            reject(error);
        })
        .once('end', async () => {
            resolve(downloadPath);
        })
        // pipe the file to the stream
        .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(downloadPath));
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone else is looking at this, here's where I landed...

```
   return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        let bucket = new mongodb.GridFSBucket(db, {
            bucketName: 'Binaries'
        });
        let objectID = new mongodb.ObjectID(fileInformation._id);

        // temporary variable to hold image
        var data = [];

        // create the download stream
        let downloadStream = bucket.openDownloadStream(objectID);
        downloadStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
            data.push(chunk);
        });
        downloadStream.on('error', async (error) => {
            reject(error);
        });
        downloadStream.on('end', async () => {
            // convert from base64 and write to file system
            let bufferBase64 = Buffer.concat(data)
            let bufferDecoded = Buffer.from(bufferBase64.toString(), 'base64');
            fs.writeFileSync(fileName, bufferDecoded, 'binary');
            resolve(fileName);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Node has a built-in buffer parser `Buffer.from(string[, encoding])` that you can pass the base64 encoded string to it, and get a stream of bytes from the other side, which you can convert it `.toString()` easily afterwards.

Ex.

```
let whatYouNeed = Buffer.from(gridFsData, 'base64').toString();
```

More about Buffer.from() function [here](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_string_encoding).

Comment: I’ve been looking at the Buffer class, but I’m struggling to see how to intercept the data being piped from GridFS output stream to the FS write stream - can you give me any pointers there?